# getting a extra variable in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am using Laravel and I am working on an existing project where I got a query

```
SELECT SUM(multi) as total
FROM ( SELECT men*hours as multi FROM report_task_manhours WHERE task_id=27013)X
```

Can anyone explain what is the use of **X** which is present in last in the query?

And it's working when I run this query in MySQL console.

Comment: Which is your database - MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: `x` is an alias for `( select men*hours as multi from report_task_manhours where task_id=27013)` as a table.

Comment: @Zhorov currently  I am working with MySQL

Comment: You should search for SQL alias for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL) NB every sub query has to have an alias.

Comment: Try it without x

Answer (score 0):

X is working as an alias of your subquery which is below

```
( select men*hours as multi from report_task_manhours where task_id=27013)
```

So if you want to use any of the other fields from your subquery to your main query then you need to use it with X.{field_name} as you can also use X.multi inside SUM function in your main query.

Like below

```
select sum(X.multi) as total from ( select men*hours as multi from report_task_manhours where task_id=27013)X
```

I hope it's clear.